# SQLite update column using value from another table doesn't work (but works well in PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Using SQLite, I need to update table1's column using value from table2. Before executing the `update` statement I extracted the value from table2 using below query and it worked without problem

```
SELECT *,CAST(table2.val AS integer)
FROM table2, table1
WHERE table1.a = table2.x AND table1.b = table2.y;
```

Above query will give me the extracted integer type of `table2.val` with the right number of row. But when I want to update certain column of table1 using the extracted value from above query, it won't give me the result and the query keep executing (never-ending).

```
UPDATE table1
SET newval= (
SELECT CAST(table2.val AS integer)
FROM table2
WHERE table1.a = table2.x AND table1.b = table2.y;
)
```

Is there anything wrong with my query? Both of my tables dont have primary key, I'm not sure if it has something to do with it.

I tried the same process in PostgreSQL using below query and it worked well.

```
UPDATE table1
SET newval= CAST(table2.val AS integer)
FROM table2
WHERE table1.a = table2.x AND table1.b = table2.y;
```

I don't know why my SQLite query doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really want to update every row of table1?

Comment: @Shawn yes, the first query gives me the result as many as table1's row and I want to insert that value to each row of table1

Comment: You should probably make that correlated subquery only return a single row, then (If it doesn't already). And an index on table2(x,y) if there isn't one already. Both of those would help with speed.